# WP WooCommerce add header image to all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a header image to all pages of the WooCommerce shop (shop, cart, checkout), however it only displays on the shop frontpage, not on the cart, or checkout pages. I created a layout PHP file in my theme directory like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="banner-parallax"></div>
<div class="container">
<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
</div><!--container-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: paste site link here with your shop page?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, go into Woocommerce and copy the file called wrapper-start.php located in templates/global.  From here, copy it into your theme inside a folder called Woocommerce and a then a folder called global.  This means the wrapper-start.php file here will override the default Woocommerce one.

You can remove most of the contents of this file and add your title here, and it will appear at the start of all Woocommerce pages.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, tried it, but has no effect, seems like WooCommerce is not calling the file in my theme folder (inside woocommerce/global)

Comment: Checked again, so it works on the shop fontpage, but not on the cart or checkout